# How to know if any given column from a SSAS live source is being used in the .pbix?

Tags: powerbi, ssas

I have a setup where I consume **live** from Analysis Services, therefore my Power BI desktop is a bit limited, in terms of what I can do there:

[image]

Usually, the SSAS I consume from, has thousands of measures, and I only use a subset of them…

Is there any way of knowing, fore example if measure X is used in any of the pages of the .pbix?

Given a column or measure; I was wondering if there is any way of quickly knowing if it is used in any visual or filter in any of the pages of the pbix...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can tackle this using an external tool such as [Power BI Helper](https://radacad.com/document-a-power-bi-file-and-report-in-a-few-clicks-all-dax-code-visualization-power-query-scripts).
The documentation part is where you should look at.